# std::map write/read from multiple threads

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to be able to read and write in a std::map from multiple threads. Is there a way to do that without mutex (maybe with std::atomic)?

If not, what's the simplest way to do that in C++11?

Comment: You need to protect your map with mutex. You may also look at this template class: https://github.com/Kicer86/openlibrary/blob/master/src/putils/ts_resource.hpp which wraps any object and makes it threadsafe.

Comment: Looks to be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338732/is-it-possbile-to-implement-lock-free-map-in-c)

Comment: @holtavolt: my impression is that this question explores whether some level of threaded operation can be achieved using `std::map` without `mutex`, while the other question looks at alternatives to `std::map` (i.e. non-Standard associative maps) for when it's decided `std::map` is insufficiently flexible. The answer to this question may well lead readers to the other question....

Comment: @Tony D - fair point - retracted, and you've provided a good answer to constraints of the std::map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the *values* are `std::atomic<>`, you can modify and read *them* from arbitrary threads, but you'll need to have saved their addresses somehow - pointers, references or iterators - and you'll need to know no other thread will call `erase` on them....

Still, even atomic values won't make it safe to modify the container (e.g. inserting or erasing elements), while other threads are also doing modifications or lookups or iteration.  Even the "`const`" functions - like `size()`, `empty()`, `begin()`, `end()`, `count()`, and iterator movement - are unsafe, because the mutating operations may be in the middle of rewiring the inter-node links or updating the same data.

For anything more than the above, you *will* need a mutex.

---

For a concrete example, say you've inserted a node with `std::string` key `"client_counter"` - you could start a thread that gets an iterator to that element and does atomic updates to the counter, while other threads can `find` the element and read from it but must not `erase` it.  You could still have other nodes inserted in the `map`, with other updaters and readers, without any extra synchronisation with the `client_counter`-updating thread.

Comment: So really, if you want to use a std::map concurrently, you'll need a _readers-writer lock_.

Comment: @Gerard: "so really" makes it sound like you are offering a handy summary of my answer, but your comment dismisses atomic ops on values and introduces a new topic - whether reader-writer locks are always preferable to the humble mutex.  While atomic access to values is *very* restrictive, I'll leave it to the OP and other readers to determine utility in their specific scenarios, and to decide on exactly which non-lockfree synchronisation mechanism to use... that's another question.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use mutex then you need to wait for concurrent containers (C++17?). If you want to use `std::atomic` operations inside `std::map` then you probably want to make or found on the Internet fully implementation of concurrent atomic `std::map`.

If you want to use `std::map` of `std::atomic` then you probably need to know that this will protect only elements inside `std::map`, but not `std::map` in self.

Comment: C++ 17 it is. patience is a virtue